# How can I tell what source IP address is used when our .NET Core application server makes a request to an external IP address restricted server?

Tags: iis, web-server, https, .net

I've been using Fiddler Classic to capture the traffic from our IIS web server on which runs a .NET core application which makes requests to an external IP address restricted servers (both test and production are IP address restricted) over HTTPS Tls1.2 only. I'm able to make successful requests to the organizations test URL from all 3 of our servers, test, uat, and production but when I make requests to the outside organization production URL those requests fail.  I've sent the external organization our public IP addresses for all 3 of our servers so they've been added to the whitelist.  What I cannot tell from the Fiddler logs is the source IP address, it just shows the loopback address, 127.0.0.1.  How can I get the source IP address of the requests that go out?

SoapUI shows an HTTP 500 internal server error for the requests to the production URL and the Event Viewer .NET Runtime error shows System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Response status code does not indicate success: 401.  I need to somehow verify what are/is the IP address(es) for the failed requests.  I would assume the requests should originate from the public IP address of each of our servers but that doesn't appear to be the case.

I've verified with our network team that the firewall isn't blocking the requests.

We have an internal desktop application that connects to our VPN which will make an HTTPS GET to our internal .NET core application server which will then in turn make an HTTPS GET to the external organizations server to return a pdf file.

Thank you

Comment: Instead of using a tool like Fiddler, try to utilize the .NET built-in tracing with some powerful tool like https://github.com/lowleveldesign/dotnet-wtrace to learn what packets are on the wire. That should be easier to find the culprit.

Comment: Maybe this question is way over my head, but if you're using NAT I don't think you're ever going to be able to tell the public IP address by inspecting traffic on the web server itself, are you? I would send a request from the web server to one of those "what is my ip address" sites, and make sure that result matches what you expect the IP to be. Something like `curl https://wtfismyip.com/text`

Comment: `I've verified with our network team` and what address are the network team seeing?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the issue was the external organization didn't permit the same IP addresses on the production server as they did on the test server which caused the network team and I a lot of grief.

Thank you for your comments.